# Combine csv files with different structures over time

Tags: powerquery

I am here to ask you a hypothetical question.

Part of my current job consists of creating and updating dashboards. Most dashboards have to be updated everyday.

I've created a PowerBI dashboard from data linked to a folder filled with csv files. I did some queries to edit some things. So, everyday, I download a csv file from a client's web application and add the said file to the linked folder, everything gets updated automatically and all the queries created are applied.

Hypothetical scenario: my client changes the csv structure (e.g. column order, a few column name). How can I deal with this so I can keep my merged csv files table updated?

My guess would be to put the files with the new structure in a different folder, apply new queries so the table structures match, then append queries so I have a single table of data.

Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it depends on how exactly you're merging the CSVs into a single table. Changes in column order shouldn't be a problem for something like `Table.Combine` as, based on what I've seen, it aligns/matches columns by name before appending. However, if you're doing something like simply combining binaries, then this assumes/relies on the column order being identical across all CSVs. If you post some of the `M`/query code, it might help.

Comment: Regarding the changes in column names, I guess it depends how big the change is. If it's something small like differences in spacing (`ColumnA` -> `Column A`) or capitilisation (`COLUMN A` -> `Column A`), maybe use some of the `Text` functions to standardise/sanitise the input. However, if the column names are totally changing, maybe create some `Records`, in which the `FieldNames` are the new/changed column names -- and the `FieldValues` are what they should be renamed to. e.g. `[columnA = "Revenue", B = "Turnover", colC = "Market cap"]`. Then map "new" headers to what they should be.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, in this case I am combining binaries, that's why I am asking this, because this method imply same file structure in each file. Maybe I should change my approach.

Comment: Yes, a different approach may be advisable. I imagine you are currently using `Folder.Files` and combining the binaries it returns. What I think you should instead do is continue to use `Folder.Files`, but then call `Csv.Document` on each binary, and then `Table.Combine`. This approach should handle any differences in column order (it won't handle any differences in column names, so that needs to be addressed separately). I can try to post an answer tomorrow, if you want more details.

Comment: Again, thank you so much. I am gonna try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say I have some CSVs (all in the same folder) that I need to append/combine into a single Excel table, but:

1. the column order varies in some CSVs,
2. and the headers in some CSVs are different (for whatever reason) and need changing/renaming.

**First CSV:**

```
a,c,e,d,b
1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3
```

**Second CSV:**

```
ALPHA,b,c,d,e
4,4,4,4,4
5,5,5,5,5
6,6,6,6,6
```

**Third CSV:**

```
a,b,charlie,d,e
7,7,7,7,7
8,8,8,8,8
9,9,9,9,9
10,10,10,10,10
```

If the parent folder (containing my CSVs) is at `"C:\Users\user\Desktop\changing csvs\csvs"`, then this `M` code should help me achieve what I need:

```
let
    renameMap = [ALPHA = "a", charlie = "c"],
    filesInFolder = Folder.Files("C:\Users\user\Desktop\changing csvs\csvs"),
    binaryToCSV = Table.AddColumn(filesInFolder, "CSVs", each
        let
            csv = Csv.Document([Content], [Delimiter = ",", Encoding = 65001, QuoteStyle = QuoteStyle.Csv]),
            promoteHeaders = Table.PromoteHeaders(csv, [PromoteAllScalars = true]),
            headers = Table.ColumnNames(promoteHeaders),
            newHeaders = List.Transform(headers, each Record.FieldOrDefault(renameMap, _, _)),
            renameHeaders = Table.RenameColumns(promoteHeaders, List.Zip({headers, newHeaders}))

        in
            renameHeaders
    ),
    append = Table.Combine(binaryToCSV[CSVs])
in
    append
```

- You'd need to change the folder path in the code to whatever it is on your system.
- Regarding this line `renameMap = [ALPHA = "a", charlie = "c"],`, I needed to change `"ALPHA"` to `"a"` and `"charlie"` to `"c"` in my case, but you'd need to replace with whatever columns need renaming in your case. (Add however many headers you need to rename.)
- This line `append = Table.Combine(binaryToCSV[CSVs])` will append the tables to one another (to give you one table). It should automatically handle differences in column order. If there any rogue columns (e.g. say there was a column `f` in one of my CSVs that I didn't notice), then my final table will contain a column `f`, albeit with some `nulls`/blanks -- which is why it's important all renaming has been done before that line.
- Once combined, you can obviously do whatever else needs doing to the table.

Try it to see if it works in your case.

Comment: I did some tests and this worked like a charm! Thank you so much!